# Deployment of a MATLAB Simulink code on Android device

Tags: android, matlab, simulink, face-detection

I've downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community version and have changed my compiler using mex -setup to Microsoft Visual C++ (2019) as well. I've also tried changing the directory but in vain. But still I'm getting this error.

"Generated code uses OpenCV and requires that you use a supported C++ compiler."

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm using the code provided in this example https://in.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/android/ref/detect-and-track-face-on-an-android-device.html  and I'm not able to generate the apk file on my android device because when I start to build this using Simulink I get the following error : "Generated code from your project uses OpenCV and requires that you use a supported C++ compiler. Use 'mex -setup' to select a supported C++ compiler."